# Error: WARNING in ./src/styles.scss (./node_modules/raw-loader!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

*Greeting fellow developers.*

I am working on the Angular 6 project. Everything is working fine but in the console, I am getting following warning after `(ng serve)` running application.

> WARNING in ./src/styles.scss
>   (./node_modules/raw-loader!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib??embedded!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--14-3!./src/styles.scss)
>   (Emitted value instead of an instance of Error) autoprefixer:
>   C:..\src\scss\layout_grid.scss:209:27:
>   auto-fill value is not supported by IE

Here is my environment details.

[image]

I have tried multiple solutions provided on StackOverflow but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do care about IE users, then you must know that auto-fill and auto-fit values for grid are not supported, and therefore provide a fallback.

If you don't care about IE users, the warning should be disabled in more recent versions of angular (> 6.1.3). See https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/pull/11453/commits/41d6af4655575381cba3afc00fa2b07109348cfb.